# Testing Javascript async await not waiting

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Why is it not waiting?

```
const wrapper = async () => {
  console.log('start');
  await setTimeout(async () => console.log('callback'),5000)
  console.log('end');
}

wrapper();
```

Result:

```
start
end
callback
```

Expected result:

```
start
callback
end
```

Comment: Because `setTimeout()` isn't an async function. For `await` to work the method you call needs to return a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to wait:

```js
const wait = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('callback'); resolve(); }, 5000)
});
const wrapper = async () => {
  console.log('start');
  await wait();
  console.log('end');
}

wrapper();
```

Comment: Thank you. I also thought of an explanation.:

await is only waiting for the **callback to be registered**. Not waiting for execution of the callback.

Comment: As mentioned above, since `setTimeout` is not async, await will not work as you used it. Wrapping it in a promise which resolves when the timer ends is the right way to do it as await works fine with the promise...

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution if the problem is solved